# how does a docker container "get" ip address with out dhcp client running inside it

Tags: linux, networking, docker

I am new to docker,trying to understand how containers **get** ip address with out a dhcp client running inside it.

when i use "docker run" its getting ip address from the same subnet as that of docker0 bridge.But how does the network interface inside the container knows about this IP and configures with that IP.

I dont see any dhclient inside the container nor a dhcp server anywhere near the container but still the containers are getting IP address.

Answer (score 0):

It is assigned one by dockerd.

Comment: Coul you shed some light into its insights.